# How to use enum data type in angular html?

Tags: angular

In my .ts file i have created an enum dataType like this:

```
export enum UploadORCompareHash {
  UPLOAD,
  COMPARE_HASH
}
@Component({
  selector: 'attachmentList',
  templateUrl: './attachment-list.component.html',
  // styleUrls: ['./attachment-list.component.css']
})
export class AttachmentListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, OnChanges {

    public uploadOrCompareHash: UploadORCompareHash;
```

Now I want to use this in my html as bellow:

```
<button *ngIf="uploadOrCompareHash === UploadORCompareHash.COMPARE_HASH" (click)="onConfirmUpload()" class="btn btn-primary"> compare hash
            </button>


<button *ngIf="uploadOrCompareHash === UploadORCompareHash.UPLOAD" (click)="onConfirmUpload()" class="btn btn-primary"> Upload
            </button>
```

but unfortunately, I can not use this. I am getting this error:

```
Property 'UploadORCompareHash' does not exist on type 'AttachmentListComponent'.
```

can someone please tell me what have I done wrong here?

Comment: what you want exactly ?

Comment: Where do you assign the uploadOrCompareHash value in component?

Answer (score 2):

You need to turn the Enum in an member of the class, like this:

```js
export enum UploadORCompareHash {
  UPLOAD,
  COMPARE_HASH
}
@Component({
  selector: 'attachmentList',
  templateUrl: './attachment-list.component.html',
  // styleUrls: ['./attachment-list.component.css']
})
export class AttachmentListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, OnChanges {

    public uploadOrCompareHash: UploadORCompareHash;
    
    get enumUpload(){
      return UploadORCompareHash
    }
```

```html
<button *ngIf="uploadOrCompareHash === enumUpload.COMPARE_HASH" (click)="onConfirmUpload()" class="btn btn-primary"> compare hash
            </button>


<button *ngIf="uploadOrCompareHash === enumUpload.UPLOAD" (click)="onConfirmUpload()" class="btn btn-primary"> Upload
            </button>
```